# .net/xslt: <xsl:include> with relative path causes error

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

My C# program has to generate different PDF documents in different versions. The basic header and footer are identical. So I would like to put them in a separate xsl.

Here the folder structure I like to have:

```
/common/headerFooter.xsl
/docVersion1/doc1.xsl
/docVersion1/doc2.xsl
...
/docVersion2/doc1a.xsl
/docVersion2/doc2a.xsl
...
```

So in fact the include in e.g. doc1.xsl should work like:

```
<xsl:include href="../common/headerFooter.xsl"/>
```

But I get the following error:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1 Content is not allowed in prolog.
System-ID unknown; Zeilennummer1; Spaltennummer1; org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Okay - first idea would be about BOM etc., but no. The files are perfectly okay (!).

So I made this try:

```
/docVersion1/headerFooter.xsl
/docVersion1/doc1.xsl
/docVersion1/doc2.xsl
...
/docVersion2/headerFooter.xsl
/docVersion2/doc1a.xsl
/docVersion2/doc2a.xsl
...
```

And in the doc1.xsl (etc.):

```
<xsl:include href="headerFooter.xsl"/>
```

This one functioned... (!?!?)

**Where is the problem?**

The relative path in the first attempt is correct. Also Visual Studio tells it. And I think it would be quite strange to put a copy of the headerFooter.xsl in each docVersion-folder.

---

Recent code:

```
// xmlToPdfInfo holds all important information about the stylesheets.
// xmlToPdfInfo.XslPath : path to the doc_.xsl-files
java.io.File xsltfile = new java.io.File(xmlToPdfInfo.XslPath);

StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(xsltfile.getAbsoluteFile());

// ERROR LINE: 
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(streamSource);
// It seems there is already an analyse for all includes and it fails to
// get the relativ path correctly.
// No chance to put additional information e.g. about the path using 
// parameters.


// Set the value of a <param> in the stylesheet);
if (xmlToPdfInfo.Arguments != null)
{
     IList keys = xmlToPdfInfo.Arguments.GetKeyList();
     foreach (var key in keys)
     {
          Object value = xmlToPdfInfo.Arguments[key];
          try
          {
              transformer.setParameter(key.ToString(), value);
          }
          catch (Exception spe)
          {
                Console.WriteLine(spe.Message);
          }                        
     }
 }
```

To remind: putting the headerFooter.xsl in the docVersion folder all works. It seems there is a problem in stepping back ( ../ ).

Comment: So you say it is .NET and C# yet the exception is about `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException` which is usually Java. Can you show us minimal but complete samples of XSLT, XML, C# to allow us to reproduce the problem? That errors occurs for instance when you try to pass a URL to a method expecting XML as a string.

Comment: I transfered the fop 2.1 jar's with IKVM 7.2.4630.5 . Quite standard. The error raises when creating a new Transformer.

Comment: But you talk about a C# program. I see no C#...

Comment: @Michael: C# and Java are really close in syntax... But you see e.g. "foreach (var key in keys)" { not for (var key : keys) } and "Console.WriteLine" { not System.out.println }

Comment: Yes, sorry, befuddled by all the Java names. I'm afraid I can't see what's wrong. It might be worth adding a URIResolver and monitoring how it gets called. Or switch to Saxon ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have got the answer myself:

The point is to write its own URIResolver! Here is my version/way:

```
public void createPDF(...) {
   ...
   xmlToPdfInfo.Resolver = new XmlResourceResolver(...);
   xmlToPdfInfo.XslPath = getPathToMyStyleSheet();
   xmlToPdfInfo.IncludedDocsList = GetIncludedDocsList();

   Utils.XmlToPdf(xmlToPdfInfo, outputStream);
}

protected SortedList GetIncludedDocsList()
{
    SortedList sortedList = new SortedList();
    sortedList.Add("headerFooter.xsl", BasePath() + ".common.headerFooter.xsl");
    ...
    return sortedList;
}
```

---

```
public class Utils
{
    private static XmlResourceResolver resolver;
    private static SortedList includedDocsList;

    /// <summary>Gets a PDF as stream from an xml-file, rendered by an xsl stylesheet</summary>
    /// <param name="xmlToPdfInfo">Contains all input information</param>
    /// <param name="outputStream">resulting PDF as a stream</param>
    public static void XmlToPdf(XmlToPdfInfo xmlToPdfInfo, OutputStream outputStream)
    {
        resolver = xmlToPdfInfo.Resolver;
        includedDocsList = xmlToPdfInfo.IncludedDocsList;
        ...
    }

    public class VgUriResolver : URIResolver
    {
        /// <summary>Gets the embedded file for the UriResolver</summary>
        /// <param name="href">relative path to the file (the path that has been put in <xsl:include>)</param>
        /// <param name="baseUri">base path</param>
        /// <returns>The embedded source </returns>
        public Source resolve(String href, String baseUri)
        {
            if (includedDocsList != null)
            {
                IList keys = includedDocsList.GetKeyList();
                String hrefFilename = Path.GetFileName(href);

                foreach (var key in keys)
                {
                    String pfad = (string) includedDocsList[key];
                    String filename = (String) key;

                    try
                    {
                        // "hard-match": if by chance we can get the file
                        // by the real resource path.
                        if (pfad.Equals(href))
                        {
                            byte[] bArr = ReadToEnd(resolver.GetManifestResourceStream(pfad));
                            return new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(bArr));
                        }

                        // "soft-match": looks for the filenames without any path. 
                        // Attention: works only fine if you **don't** have to include files
                        // with same name (different path)                          
                        if (filename.Equals(hrefFilename))
                        {
                            byte[] bArr = ReadToEnd(resolver.GetManifestResourceStream(pfad));
                            return new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(bArr));
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            return readFromFileStream(href);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            return readFromFileStream(hrefFilename);
                        }
                    }
                }                 
            }
            return new StreamSource(new StringReader(href));
        }
    }

}
```

In fact then what you write in  is more a key/placeholder to find the real file with the own URIResolver.

Well...